# Data not showing up on Wamp server database (using php)

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I'm trying to `INSERT` data into a table in my database but I'm not able to. I'm using WAMP.

PHP Script:

```
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$db = 'comments_schema';
$host = 'localhost:3306';

$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', $user, $password, $db);

$sql = "INSERT INTO parent_comment(commentid, comment) VALUES ('". '   
commentid'."', '". "hi" ."')";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if($result > 0):
    echo 'Successfully posted';
else:
    echo 'Unable to post';
endif;
```

HTML Code:

```
</div>
    <form action="database.php" method="post">
        Comments: <input type="text" name="field_name" />
        <input type="Submit" /></form>
```

However, the rows could not be inserted:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Every time you leave a root/admin (database or other) password blank, a fairy dies. Please set one on your database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use backticks for SQL-related elements, ands single quotes around the values you want to insert.

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO `parent_comment` (commentid, comment)
VALUES ('commentid', 'hi')
";
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code:

```
'INSERT INTO parent_comment(commentid, comment) VALUES ('.commentid.', "hi")';
```

Comment: No no no. To avoid SQL injection, use a prepared statement or escape commentid.

Comment: Thank @PhilLello :) its true